# Is it possbile to set two different text color in excel cell programatically

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm trying to find a way to change the color of a line of text in an excell cell
programatically. I know how to change the backcolor of a cell but not the text color.

```
  Dim style_green As Excel.Style = xlSheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("Green")

  xlSheet.Cells(1, 1).Style = "Green"
```

For example I would like to have 3 lines in a cell

line1 - color blue

line2 - color red

line3 - color green

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cYou Can change it using:

```
xlSheet.Cells(1, 1).Characters(Start,Length).Font.Color = vbRed
```

But you need to find `Start` and `Length` parameters for each line first.

Comment: A side note: AFAIK, data should be available in the cell first, (.Value2 = yourArray) if you did not bind the data first and tried to change the color, nothing will happen.

Comment: @NeverHopeless thank you. Using the information you gave me I got this going and I have minor tweaks to when remembering length of strings.
Problem almost solved